# GADBannerViewDelegate doesn't fire adViewDidReceiveAd in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, admob

I use GADBannerView in another class that named Tools. But adViewDidReceiveAd delegate method doesn't fire in Tools class. What can I do?

```
class Tools: NSObject, GADBannerViewDelegate {

    var viewController: UIViewController!

    func showAds(viewController: UIViewController) -> Void {

        self.viewController = viewController

        let request: GADRequest = GADRequest()
        request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]

        let bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
        bannerView.delegate = self
        bannerView.rootViewController = viewController
        bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-xxx-xxx"
        bannerView.loadRequest(request)

    }

    func adViewDidReceiveAd(bannerView: GADBannerView!) {
        print("adViewDidReceiveAd");
        viewController.view.addSubview(bannerView)
    }
}
```

And, I called Tools in ViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    Tools().showAds(self);
}
```

Comment: any news on this issue?

Comment: Hi! I am having the same issue: adViewDidReceiveAd is not called. Did you find the problem?

Answer (score 4):

In my case.. change from

```
func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
  print("adViewDidReceiveAd")
}
```

to

```
func bannerViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
  print(#function)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem then I replaced the

```
private func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: DFPBannerView) {}
```

with

```
func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {}
```

then problem is solved. I hope it helps you, too.

Comment: For the quick reader: **DFPBannerView** is changed to **GADBannerView**. By the way: an excellent answer!

Comment: I am happy to help people who searched too much to find the correct answer, just like me.. @TonSnoei :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a bug. After creating bannerView you did not add it into a viewcontroller. Thus it will be deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I faced the same issue and I checked that the failed delegate is calling in mine case. Kindly check the error and If you face the same and the error is 'No ad to display' then make sure that your app is uploaded to APP STORE and same has been verified by the Admob by linking it.

```
 func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView,
        didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
    }
```

Once it has been done your adViewDidReceiveAd delegate will call.