# adMob banner not shown using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, admob

Here is my code.Its strange i can seen full ad but it does not shown banner in simulator or real device and i also can no seen any error log. I just shown log for AdMob version. I don't know what happen here. If anything wrong in my code please help me.

> Google Mobile Ads SDK version: afma-sdk-i-v7.7.0

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {

var bannerView:GADBannerView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)

        bannerView?.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-0074244033587929/9554929828"
        bannerView?.delegate = self
        bannerView?.rootViewController = self
        self.view.addSubview(bannerView!)
        let request:GADRequest = GADRequest()
        request.testDevices = ["65e9360edef670258b91c55321caed08"]
        bannerView?.loadRequest(request)

        print("Google Mobile Ads SDK version: " + GADRequest.sdkVersion())
}
//GADBannerViewDelegate
    func adViewDidReceiveAd(view: GADBannerView!) {
        print("adViewDidReceiveAd:\(view)");
        bannerView?.hidden = true
    }

    func adView(view: GADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError!) {
        print("\(view) error:\(error)")
        bannerView?.hidden = false
    }

    func adViewWillPresentScreen(adView: GADBannerView!) {
        print("adViewWillPresentScreen:\(adView)")
       bannerView?.hidden = false
    }

    func adViewWillLeaveApplication(adView: GADBannerView!) {
        print("adViewWillLeaveApplication:\(adView)")
        bannerView?.hidden = false
    }

    func adViewWillDismissScreen(adView: GADBannerView!) {
        print("adViewWillDismissScreen:\(adView)")
        bannerView?.hidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you can try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34843019/gadbannerviewdelegate-doesnt-fire-adviewdidreceivead-in-swift/54800950#54800950

Answer (score 0):

Did you add all frameworks mentioned here.
[Please cross check](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start#load_an_ad_into_gadbannerview)

Comment: is your test device is proper ?

Comment: Yes it is. But i also can not call any delegate methods for GADBannerView.

Comment: once you should check bannerView's delegate and outlet connections.

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps:

1. Install `GoogleMobileAds` sdk from Cocoapods.
2. Create a view in ViewController and assign its class as `GADBannerView`
3. Here is the code :

import UIKit

import GoogleMobileAds

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var viewBanner: GADBannerView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Advertisement
    viewBanner.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
    viewBanner.rootViewController = self
    viewBanner.loadRequest(GADRequest())

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}